# How to resolve "RuntimeError: Unable to export GPIO. Try to run as root!"?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, root

I have interfaced a push button switch and LEDs to GPIO.

Whenever I try to execute the script from command line, the code `python /home/myPi/myProject/run.py` gives me the error

> RuntimeError: Unable to export GPIO. Try to run as root!

But if the same script works perfectly with `sudo python /home/myPi/myProject/run.py`

How to resolve this error?
I want to run the script at startup.

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: There is no error. Some things require root privileges and apparently Python's runtime support for GPIO is one of those things. When you use the sudo command, your user profile is treated as if it was "root". So you could use the sudo command in your startup script. Also please note that some startup things on Linux actually run as root, so your script running at startup MAY not even need root/sudo. Try it. Sorry I am not more of an expert or I would give you more specifics.

Answer (score 2):

Running Python as root is a **VERY BAD IDEA** but used to be necessary with some Python GPIO modules.

It should not be necessary anymore as long as you are using a reasonably up to date Raspbian system.

Make sure your user (assumed to be pi) is a member of the gpio group.

`sudo adduser pi gpio`

Answer (score 1):

The error is trying to tell you what to do

```
Try to run as root!
```

To run a command as `root`, you put the word `sudo` at the start of the command you want to execute. Your command should look like

```
sudo python /home/myPi/myProject/run.py
```

Be careful using `sudo`, using it gives you full permissions and you could break your operating system with it.

Answer (score 1):

gpio library need `sudo` privileges so you should run your program `sudo python yourProgram.py`.

Unless there is a specific reason I would suggest to use Python3: `sudo python3 yourProgram.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where it wouldn't run programs without root access. I solved it by running the file from the terminal. To do this first go to the directory your file is in then type this:

```
sudo python your-filename.py
```